# Informatica - could not delete workflow in WORKFLOW MONITOR

Tags: session, mapping, etl, informatica-powercenter

Created a mapping, workflow, session and executed successfully. Decided to delete the mapping, workflow,session (not source / target) and finally deleted.

Followed various procedures like edit-delete, view history-Purge, Delete manually through the folder of particular mapping. But could not delete the workflow in WORKFLOW MONITOR only. So, due to this I could not create a new workflow on the same name and also shows that there is already a name being registered with this name but no file available.

Attached an image of the workflows being available within the workflow monitor. The red circle in the image are the workflows I have deleted.

Thankyou

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow monitor just displays the stats and log. There is nothing to delete from Workflow monitor. You have to delete it from Workflow Manager only. After deleting it from the folder, go to Versioning -> Find Checkouts and check-in the workflow. I think that should work.

Comment: Yes that works. Thankyou.
But check-in / check-out is available in Versioning in Informatica 9.6.1 not in view.

Comment: Glad it worked. Updated the answer with Versioning -> Find Checkouts